# Check Home Page Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, development

How to check page is homepage/default page programmatically in C# sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

`SPContext.Current.ContextPageInfo.IsWebWelcomePage`

Answer (score 0):

To know if a web page is the default page of a SharePoint web site (or any folder) in c# you can use the `SPFolder.WelcomePage` property. This property return a URL for the default page so you can compare it with the URL of the page you want to test.

*Example to test if a page is default for a SharePoint site:*

```
// After you get the SPWeb object...
string defaultPageUrl = web.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
if(defaultPageUrl == <Test Page Url>)
{
  <Test Page Url> is the default page.
}
```

Comment: I was researching myself the answer, so I would like to complete yours: `string defaultPageUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.ServerRelativeUrl,web.RootFolder.WelcomePage);` and <Test Page Url> should be `this.Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath`. Then the comparison will work indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a page as home page through sharepoint designer but if you need to check it is home page or not check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontextpageinfo.iswebwelcomepage.aspx